# Why can't Intellij recognize my genymotion?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I install Genymotion and I also add some devices in it.
after that I install plugin for Genymotion in intellij and Now I can see Genymotion icon in toolbar.
But the Problem is that when I want to run my application, although I select the show chooser dialog in Edit Configuration, Intellij can't recognize my Genymotion.

what should I do?

Comment: you mean that on run chooser dialog show no device (not an emulator) ?

Comment: yes I choose it . I choose "show chooser dialog "

Comment: no , i mean does the device show in the "Android" Tab inside toolbar ?

Comment: nothing show . I just can see my real device . no genymotion

Comment: try to restart your adb process...

Comment: where is adb process . how can I find adb?

Comment: sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server
this will kill the adb process and second command again start the adb
adb command is inside <sdk-path>/platform-tools directory of your system

Comment: Very unreliable. One time it works one tme not. Restarting adb doesn't work. restart pc yes. very efficient.